# Update model parameter with new data, discarding old data

Tags: regression, machine-learning, estimation, polynomial, online-algorithms

I have [this](https://pastebin.com/A3s9dUKp) dataset, and I am using `y = (a * x^n) / (b + x^n)` Hill function as the model, where `a` is the limit of the Hill curve, `b` is the point at which `a/2` is reached (for `n` = 1) and `n` is the cooperativity or steepness of the curve.

Currently, I am storing all `X,y` values, computing the parameters from `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`, and plotting the curve. If new data points come along, I re-calculate the parameters with the old+new data.

Is there a way to update the parameters of the model without storing **all** of the previous old data points, once the initial parameters are obtained from the previous data points?

Example, I fit the curve to the first 1000 data points and have my parameters. Next, I discard some or all of the old data. Then, when I see the 1001st point I simply update my parameters and plot the curve again and so on for every new data point.

**EDIT**

My existing code is as follows (not super elegant).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def file_stream(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            yield map(float, line.strip().split('\t'))

def hill_model(X, a, b, n):
    return [float((a * x**n)) / (b + x**n) for x in X]

def get_params(X_all, y_all, prev_par=None, fn=hill_model):
    if prev_par is None:
        a_init, b_init, n_init = y_all[-1], y_all[0], 1.0
    else:
        a_init, b_init, n_init = prev_par
    opt_par, opt_cov = curve_fit(fn, X_all, y_all, p0=[a_init, b_init, n_init])
    a_final, b_final, n_final = opt_par
    return a_final, b_final, n_final

def main():
    file_name     = 'data.tsv'
    file_streamer = file_stream(file_name)
    X_all, y_all  = [], []

    # Get some intial data from stream
    for _ in xrange(1000):
        X, y = file_streamer.next()
        X_all.append(X)
        y_all.append(y)
    plt.scatter(X_all, y_all)

    # Initialize params of model
    a, b, n = get_params(X_all, y_all)
    y_model = hill_model(X_all, a, b, n)
    plt.plot(X_all, y_model, 'r-')
    plt.show()

    # Rolling update
    seen_all = False # Helps stop when all data is fit
    while True:
        for _ in xrange(1000):
            try:
                X, y = file_streamer.next()
                X_all.append(X)
                y_all.append(y)
            except:
                seen_all = True
                break
        a, b, n = get_params(X_all, y_all, prev_par=[a, b, n], fn=hill_model)
        y_model = hill_model(X_all, a, b, n)
        plt.scatter(X_all, y_all)
        plt.plot(X_all, y_model, 'r-')
        plt.show()

        # Nothing more to update, return
        if seen_all:
            return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code currently reads in some `X,y` values, calculates the `a`, `b`, `n` parameters and when more `X,y` values are added, the code updates `a`, `b`, and `n` params. As you can see, I need to store previous `X,y` values, which I do not **want**. I want to update the parameters as new `X,y` values are seen and from the previous `a`, `b`, and `n` values only.

Comment: Model updates to add an observation are straightforward with linear models, but I don't think it's going to be the case with nonlinear models, since adding observations will change the estimates -- and hence the weights to all observations under a linear approximation at the current optimum. Since each update (when you're adding one point to many) won't change the estimate much, the linear approximation will be a really good start but as soon as you take that update step you'd not quite be at the optimum and to improve that you'd update the approximation for all of the data.

Comment: Interesting @Glen_b! But I see this blog post which shows how to derive the incremental form for any polynomial regression: (http://erikerlandson.github.io/blog/2012/07/05/deriving-an-incremental-form-of-the-polynomial-regression-equations/) I get the concept, but given the power of `x` which is `n` in my case is a model parameter, I have no idea how to use the concept discussed in the post for my particular case.

Comment: Polynomial regression is *linear* in the intended sense (which is why you were able to find an update formula), but your model is not linear in the required sense.

Comment: Hmmm. So it's hopeless I guess. I dunno. At this point I have almost given up. But, no other model will fit the datasets as nicely as this one. Sucks.

Comment: I note you are asking essentially the same question on math.SE ... please note the third-last paragraph near the end of our on-topic page of the [help/on-topic]

Comment: I was unaware. I am new to Stack Exchange sites. I will delete the one in Math tomorrow morning. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: No need to delete now it's there, but please keep in mind for future.

Comment: I don't think the situation is exactly *hopeless*; there's a variety of things that might be done which may help, depending on what your actual needs are; approximate solutions might be possible in various ways, for example.

Comment: I have this stream of Iteration (X) vs observations made (y) data flowing through. It so happens that this Hill function model very nicely captures the asymptotic behavior of the process. So I was planning to keep a running estimate of the limit (parameter a) of the curve as new observations were being made without storing all the accumulating data.

Comment: Once the y in some X equal some threshold fraction of the integer part of limit, I could then stop the observation process.

Comment: How much noise do you have around the curve? How close to accurate is the constant variance assumption? How necessary are exact solutions? What is the constraint you're trying to deal with? Is it just storage space?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean in that last comment there, but it sounds like there's good opportunity for some degree of approximation. It might be possible to work with a transformed response and variance weighting.

Comment: There is no noise. Every data point is a true value of the process. Exact solution enables me to stop the stream once I reach some threshold fraction of the limit. The constraint is truly the storage space, hence my search for some kind of on-line algorithm.

Comment: Clarification: so, if I see some y and it's p% of the current limit (parameter a) estimate I would stop observing.

Comment: If you have no noise there's no problem transforming. Wait -- but the model doesn't fit perfectly, right? Otherwise the first 3 points would suffice!

Comment: Okay, could you then answer the question with your solution?

Comment: No but it's better than everything else I have tried.

Comment: No, turns out I can't because (i) your claim of "no noise" isn't correct in the intended sense (the curve doesn't actually go through the points) and (ii) the [Hill equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_equation_(biochemistry)) that I was looking at restricts y to between 0 and 1, which is not the case for your data, so the transformation I was thinking of wouldn't work.